# Compactness of a subset of $W^{2, \infty}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)$

Tags: functional-analysis

i would like to know if the following subset in $W^{2, \infty}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)$

$$
\mathcal B:=\{b\in W^{2, \infty}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d):||b||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)}\leq M,\ ||\operatorname{div}b\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d)}\leq M\}\quad\text{for a given $M>0$}
$$

is compact in $L^2(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)$.

I think that this is not true because the only hypothesis on $\operatorname{div}$ is not enough to guarantee the equi-boundedness of derivatives of $b$. Indeed i think that if i have a subsequence $b_n\in W^{1, \infty}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)$ such that $||\operatorname{div}b_n||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d)}\leq M$ and $\|b_n\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)}\leq M$ then this does not imply that $\|b_n\|_{W^{1, \infty}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)}\leq M$. If this was true, i would have that $\mathcal B\subset\subset W^{1, \infty}\subset\subset L^2$ on compact subsets. Could you help me/give me some useful suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have compactness for function spaces on all of $\mathbb R^n$. Take $\phi$ a non-zero smooth function, supported on $(0,1)$. Then define the sequence $\phi_n(x):=\phi(x+n)$. It will not have a converging subsequence.